# Automating replies in Outlook 2010/2013

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, microsoft-outlook-2013

I am trying to automate replies in Outlook. I want to single hot key that will reply to the sender with a pre-written response. Upon hitting the key combination, I want the reply to be composed and then sent in one stroke.

I know I can create a response using Quick Steps, but then I still have to take the additional step of sending (and of course, it wants to spell check on the way).

I want one step.

Is there a built in feature in Outlook to do this or is VBA the only way?

ps: I have searched for an answer here and elsewhere and will continue to do so.

Comment: So, is you actual question how to accomplish this? Because as written, "*Is VBA the only way?*", it is not asking that. You also need to tell us what you have attempted so far and share any code you are working with.

Comment: Charlie, I did say what I tried, QuickSteps described in paragraph #2. I know its also possible via VBA. I am asking of there are alternatives other than writing a VBA script. Also, a down vote, really? Perfectly valid question (and yes, I searched for an answer already). Sunk818, I'm not 12 and don't need to check my work (btw, spell check checks the reply text in the subject as well). I know what I want to do.

Answer (score 0):

VBA is not the only way. You can use a $79 software called [Email Templates](http://www.emailtemplates.com/features.aspx) to automate your replies. This is an add-on to Outlook that has all the features you want:

- Reply To Messages With a Single Click